# How to add Back Button In Print Preview Page-Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

How can i add a back button in Print preview page in JQuery Data table?

By default table tools using escape key for navigating to original page. Instead i need a back button in preview page, so that by clicking on it, it will navigate to previous page. Back button should have same functionality as escape button currently doing.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'private' method in TableTools that should help here called `_fnPrintEnd` which you can use to this end. You just need to add something to click to `sMessage` and then bind an event to it.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/linssen/eQKBn/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    var oTableTools = new TableTools(oTable, {
        "aButtons": [{
            "sExtends": "print",
                "sMessage": '<div class="datatables-print-msg">' +
                '<a class="btn close-print" href="#">Close print view</a>' +
                '</div>'
        }]
    });

    // Inject the tabletools HTML before the table
    oTable.before(oTableTools.dom.container);

    // Bind our close function to the button we will prepend
    // must use delegate because the button won't exist yet.
    $(document).delegate(".datatables-print-msg .close-print", "click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        oTableTools._fnPrintEnd(e);
    });
});
```